# OLS difference between individual level and aggregate level estimates

Tags: least-squares, aggregation, fallacy, ecology

I am new here, so please accept my apologies if this does not belong here.
My question essentially concerns what appears to me a special case of the ecological fallacy. Consider a simple model that could be estimated via OLS:
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i
$$

Now imagine, I were to have a further variable that partitions my observations into $M$ groups. Assume for simplicity that each group has the same size. For each group $m$, I now take the averages of $x$ and $y$, i.e $\bar{x}_m$ and $\bar{y}_m$. I then run the regression:
$$
\bar{y}_m = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \bar{x}_m + \epsilon_m
$$

Here is my question: 
Under what conditions do the estimates of $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ differ?

Many thanks for your help!